# how can I have 2 normal sides of a plane?

Tags: mesh, normals

I notice that some obj that I import into blender in a plane shape (like a cape, wall) both face sides are visible, instead of only one as a default in blender

I would like to know how to configure that in a new mesh in blender. Currently I have to use box for such requirement that increases complexity modeling it and creating unnecessary faces

thanks

Comment: "both face sides are visible, instead of only one as a default in blender" What do you mean ? Is it about Backface Culling from the *Properties* shelf > *Shading* rollout ? It should be turned off by default.

Comment: Are you using blender internal or cycles?

Comment: When I used to export to iClone via 3Dxchange, the backface culling would always be on even though it would be turned off in Blender when I did the export.   When I'd do the reverse and import models back into Blender, both faces would be visible.  It might depend on the application you're exporting a model to.